# Why aren't globular clusters disk-shaped?

Tags: gravity, solar-system

I thought that solar systems and galaxies are disk-shaped because that is the most stable shape under gravitation. Globular clusters are very old, often times older than their host galaxies, so why haven't they flattened out?